# Python SQLite3 printing result of two combined tables makes problems

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem programming a sqlite3 database in Python.

So I made two lists:

`idata=[(0,"Ingredient1"),
        (1,"Ingredient2")]`

This is the first one that holds "Ingredients" and their ID's.

```
rdata=[(0,"Recipie1",0,1,1)]
```

And this is the second one that holds "Recipies" their ID's and and three numbers that indicate the ID of the "Ingredients" to be used in this "Recipie".

Then I created two tables that I filled with the data of these lists:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect ("Alchemy_Data_Bank.dat")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipie(id, name, iid_1, iid_2, iid_3);
""")
c.executemany("insert into recipie(id, name, iid_1, iid_2, iid_3) values (?,?,?,?,?)", rdata)

c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredient(id, name);
""")
c.executemany("insert into ingredient(id, name) values (?,?)", idata)


conn.commit()
```

And now I want to print out the "Recipies" together with their "Ingredients" combined in a table. So I did this:

```
for p in c.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT recipie.name,
                   CASE WHEN recipie.iid_1 = ingredient.id THEN ingredient.name end,
                   CASE WHEN recipie.iid_2 = ingredient.id THEN ingredient.name end,
                   CASE WHEN recipie.iid_3 = ingredient.id THEN ingredient.name end
                   FROM recipie, ingredient;"""):
print(p)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

What I hoped to get as output is somethin like this:

```
('Recipie1','Ingredient1', 'Ingredient2', 'Ingredient2')
```

But it printed this:

```
('Recipie1', None, None, None)
('Recipie1', None, 'Ingredient2', 'Ingredient2')
('Recipie1', 'Ingedient1', None, None)
```

I think that my problem lies within the CASE WHEN statments as the programm compares recipie.iid_1, recipie.iid_2 and recipie.iid_3 only with one value for ingredient.id at a time.
So far as I've come the solution must be recursive slection in each CASE WHEN statment but I just can't figure out how to do that.

I hope that someone of you can tell me how to do that!

Thanks in advance!!

Cazo0

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite a query. e.g.:

```
qry1 = """select name,  
    (select name from ingredient where ingredient.id = recipie.iid_1), 
    (select name from ingredient where ingredient.id = recipie.iid_2), 
    (select name from ingredient where ingredient.id = recipie.iid_3)
from recipie;"""

rsl = c.execute(qry1)
for r in rsl:
    print (r)
```

see my gist for the whole code:
https://gist.github.com/mh70cz/5cfa595b455e87d7c08da5315b1abd21

Comment: Rewriting a query helped. The code work fine now Thank you very much! @mh70